# whole php code getting printed instead of just what's in echo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have made a very small code in which i just want to show what's in echo through div with ajax but it shows me the whole php script instead of what's in echo , can someone help me

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function test() {   
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   
if (xmlHttp !== null) {
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
        var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
                alert("Match");
                alert(response);
                document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = response;
             }           
     }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET","try.php",true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
 }
 </script>
<body>          
Enter answer: <input type="text" onKeyUp="test();"><br />
See returned value: <div id="show"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

this is my php file , i just wanted to check if it prints what's in echo so it's small

```
<?php
 echo "i just want to see if this get's printed";
?>
```

Comment: what is the code in try.php

Comment: Are you doing this on a server? It's possible that the PHP isn't being interpreted as such...

Comment: @Source Why would that make a difference?

Comment: It sounds like the .php file isn't being parsed by the web server - what happens if you attempt to access it directly in the browser?

Comment: Did you forget to put `<?php` at the beginning of the PHP file?

Comment: btw is your php code in short tags, if yes, please convert that to long tags

Comment: i have put my code in the question , now

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference, its just some advice to make it so much easier.

Comment: no no , i got the error , i was running the code locally , that's why , but when i ran it on the website it worked , thanks everyone , but i swear i can i tried running it on my website before but it didn't work then , oh well thanks again everyone , sorry for disturbing 
one question should i delete my question, cause it was my dumb mistake

Answer (score 1):

Check the Network tab in your browser's development console.  In Chrome, press F12, go to the "Network" tab, execute your `test()` function, and check the appropriate response in the Network results.  You can see the result in the "Response" tab.  Similar consoles should exist for other browsers.

Comment: no no , i got the error , i was running the code locally , that's why , but when i ran it on the website it worked , thanks everyone , but i swear i can i tried running it on my website before but it didn't work then , oh well 
one question should i delete my question, cause it was my dumb mistake

Comment: Regardless of the mistake, the question of "how can I view echoed content in an AJAX request from a PHP script" is a valid question with a useful answer.  But, it's up to you.